# transform non-numeric data to numeric data with R

Tags: r

I have a csv file with this format :

```
android ; login.html , connect.json , page1.json 

windows ; login.html , connect.json , page1.json , page2.html , page5.html 

windows ; login.html , connect.json , page4.json
```

To do PCA multivariate analysis with these variables, these variable must be numeric like this :

```
1 ; 3  

0 ; 5

0 ; 3
```

0 or 1 to indicate whether windows or android followed by the number of pages.
I am looking for a way to modify these non numeric data
Any idea please?
Best

Comment: Read in with the delimiter as `";"`, use `count.fields` on the second column and `==` for the first column....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `strsplit` and `lengths`:

```
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, sep = ";", as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
transform(DF, V1 = as.numeric(V1 == "android"), V2 = lengths(strsplit(V2, ",")))
```

giving:

```
  V1 V2
1  1  3
2  0  5
3  0  3
```

**Note:** We used this input:

```
Lines <- "android ; login.html , connect.json , page1.json 
windows ; login.html , connect.json , page1.json , page2.html , page5.html 
windows ; login.html , connect.json , page4.json"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach:

```
data.frame(V1 = as.numeric(mydf$V1 == "android"), 
           V2 = count.fields(textConnection(mydf$V2), sep = ","))
#   V1 V2
# 1  1  3
# 2  0  5
# 3  0  3
```

Sample data:

```
mydf <- read.table(
  header = FALSE, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE,
  text = '"android" ; "login.html , connect.json , page1.json" 
"windows" ; "login.html , connect.json , page1.json , page2.html , page5.html" 
"windows" ; "login.html , connect.json , page4.json"')
```